# Auto-Cast values in the correct type of the related property

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I have the following situation:

```
//...
final Criteria dbCriteriaQuery = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(User.class);
searchCriterias.forEach(searchCriteria -> addCriteriaRestrictionForUserClass(dbCriteriaQuery, searchCriteria));
final List list = dbCriteriaQuery.list();
//...

private void addCriteriaRestrictionForUserClass(Criteria criteria, SearchCriteria search) {
        final SimpleExpression property;

        switch (search.getOperator()) {
            case ">": property = Restrictions.gt(search.getPropertyName(), search.getSearchValue()); break;
            case "<": property = Restrictions.lt(search.getPropertyName(), search.getSearchValue()); break;
            case "=": property = Restrictions.eq(search.getPropertyName(), search.getSearchValue()); break;
            case "<>": property = Restrictions.ne(search.getPropertyName(), search.getSearchValue()); break;
            default: throw new InvalidDtoException();
        }

        criteria.add(property);
    }
```

I get an Exception at `search.getSearchValue()`. The problem is, that those values are always Strings, while the linked property of `User.class` can be of any type.

Is there a way to get an auto-casting here? Or do I really need to find out the type of the property first -> cast the String value to whatever type of Object and THEN put it into the query?

There is the possibility to do something like this:

```
Restrictions.gtProperty(x, y);
```

Casting works here, but you need real properties on both sides, that are somehow linked to the query.

I think this should be implemented already somewhere. All this algorithm would have to do is determine the type of the `property` and cast the `value` in the appropriate format.

Comment: FYI: I wouldn't be using the Hibernate Criteria API as it has been deprecated.  If you want to use a Criteria-builder like API, you should be using the JPA CriteriaBuilder API instead.